# 502 Bad Gateway - calling scoring api endpoint

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-ml

I'm using the following code from the community notebook **Predict outdoor equipment purchase with IBM Watson Machine Learning**:

```
...
<code omitted for brevity>
...

import urllib3, requests, json
​
headers = urllib3.util.make_headers(basic_auth='{}:{}'.format(username, password))
url = '{}/v2/identity/token'.format(service_path)
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
mltoken = json.loads(response.text).get('token')

endpoint_online = service_path + "/v2/online/deployments/"
header_online = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': mltoken}
payload_online = {"artifactVersionHref": saved_model.meta.prop("modelVersionHref"), "name": "Product Line Prediction"}
​
response_online = requests.post(endpoint_online, json=payload_online, headers=header_online)
​
print response_online
print response_online.text

scoring_href = json.loads(response_online.text).get('entity').get('scoringHref')
print scoring_href
```

The response

```
<Response [201]>
{"metadata":{"guid":"4148","href":"https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net/v2/online/deployments/4148","createdAt":"2017-06-13T07:54:16.062Z","modifiedAt":"2017-06-13T07:54:16.062Z"},"entity":{"scoringHref":"https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net/32768/v2/scoring/4148"}}
https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net/32768/v2/scoring/4148
```

Next attempt to score:

```
payload_scoring = {"record":["M", 23, "Single", "Student"]}
response_scoring = requests.put(scoring_href, json=payload_scoring, headers=header_online)
​
print response_scoring.text
```

The response:

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retried the call a few minutes later and the call was successful:

```
{
 "result":{
      "PROFESSION_IX":6.0,
      "GENDER_IX":0.0,
      "MARITAL_STATUS_IX":1.0,
      "GENDER":"M",
      "features":{
         "values":[
            0.0,
            23.0,
            1.0,
            6.0
         ]
      },
      "predictedLabel":"Personal Accessories",
      "prediction":1.0,
      ...
}
```